# How to get private Elastic-Beanstalk Environment DNS Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internal-dns, elastic-beanstalk

**My setup is the following:**
i have a VPC consisting of 3 subnets: public, private with NAT and isolated.
I have an elastic beanstalk (single instance) environment running in the private subnet with Nat and it works.

**What i want to achieve:**
have a private hosted zone with a record pointing to my private EB env.

**What i'm struggling with:**
the environment DNS of my EB env points to its **public** ip (which is not reachable since its in a private subnet and thats good). But to create a DNS record pointing to my private EB env i need a **private** endpoint of my env, right?
How do i get a URL like the public one for my env (e.g. myapp.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com) but resolving to my private ip, not the public one?

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to get a private DNS for my single instance EB env but solved it by hardcoding the instances internal IP into my DNS record. However this is suboptimal since the ip changes when i redeploy the env. 
As i understand this is not a problem when using a private load balanced (multi instance) eb env in a private subnet.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and ended up going the same route you mentioned in your comment -- hardcoding the private ipv4 in a **route53 record.**

However we were able to automate the process, mostly:

### Add EB ENVs to target Route 53 Record

Find the **Hosted Zone ID** for the domain you'll be updating. Will be listed in the **Hosted Zones** section of Route 53 and look like `Z1GP4MFDYUK339`

Choose a **Record Name** that you'll want to update within that zone. Will be like `subdomain.example.com`

In your Elastic Beanstalk **Environment properties** add the following:

- `HOSTED_ZONE` --> Hosted Zone ID
- `APP_DOMAIN` --> Record Name

### Create [.ebextensions command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) to update record on deploy

In your app's project (root) directory create the following file

```
.ebextensions/99_dns.config
```

The contents of `99_dns.config`:

```
commands:
  01_update_r53:
    command: |
        IP=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
        APP_DOMAIN=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k APP_DOMAIN)
        HOSTED_ZONE=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k HOSTED_ZONE)
        echo "{\"Comment\":\"Update IP\",\"Changes\":[{\"Action\": \"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\":{\"Name\":\""$APP_DOMAIN".\",\"Type\":\"A\",\"TTL\":60,\"ResourceRecords\":[{\"Value\":\""$IP"\"}]}}]}" > awsr53.json
        aws route53 change-resource-record-sets \
            --hosted-zone-id "$HOSTED_ZONE" \
            --change-batch file://awsr53.json
```

When your application is deployed it will:

- query for its local (private) IP address
- get the `APP_DOMAIN` and `HOSTED_ZONE` values you set from ENVs
- use the `aws` cli to create/update the record at `HOSTED_ZONE@RECORD` to be an `A` record with a value of the private address

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Matt was very useful to me, it worked. But I had to make some changes:

```
commands:
  01_update_r53:
    command: |
      IMDSTOKEN=$(curl --silent -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")
      IP=$(curl --silent -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $IMDSTOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
      AWS_R53_APP_DOMAIN=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k AWS_R53_APP_DOMAIN)
      AWS_R53_HOSTED_ZONE=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k AWS_R53_HOSTED_ZONE)
      echo "{\"Comment\":\"Update IP\",\"Changes\":[{\"Action\": \"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\":{\"Name\":\""$AWS_R53_APP_DOMAIN".\",\"Type\":\"A\",\"TTL\":60,\"ResourceRecords\":[{\"Value\":\""$IP"\"}]}}]}" > awsr53.json
      aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "$AWS_R53_HOSTED_ZONE" --change-batch file://awsr53.json
```

This needs to assign to the service role used by the instance permissions to perform an upsert on Route53. I suggests to perform the script mentioned before via SSH first to debug